# Handlebars.js breaking JQuery Mobile formatting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm having a problem with showing JQuery Mobile icon buttons on a listview using a Handlebars template: the buttons' icons won't display.

Everything works fine otherwise, the template generates the list, but the buttons' icons aren't displayed. The buttons do work when clicked, and if I add some character between the  tags it displays properly and works when clicked.

If I simply copy/paste the content of the template into the HTML document, the icon displays fine. It's only when being generated by the template that it doesn't display.

I'm using jquery mobile 1.4.2 and Handlebars 2.0.

**EDIT**: JSFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/6x9s9ys4/

This is the HTML:

```
<div data-role="content">               
    <ul id="audioList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" >             
        <!-- audioList-template -->                     
    </ul>               
</div>
```

This is the template:

```
<script id="audioList-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#.}}
    <li class="ui-grid-a" data-id="{{this.id}}">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <p>{{this.name}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b">
            <a href="#" id="btnAddFavorite" data-icon="star" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
            <a href="#" id="btnAddToCart" data-icon="plus" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext" ></a>
            <a href="#" data-icon="audio" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext"></a>                          
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/.}}
</script>
```

And this is the JS:

```
$('#audioList').empty();
var audioListHandler = Handlebars.compile($("#audioList-template").html());
$('#audioList').html(audioListHandler(audioList));         
$('#audioList').listview().listview('refresh');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works fine http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/r9nqrkr0/

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get a solution from your comment. Also tried repacing my JS with the code below, to no effect: `var source = $("#audioList-template").html(),
        template = Handlebars.compile(source),
        html = template(audioList);
  $("#audioList").html(html);
  $("#audioList").listview();`

Comment: Here it is, it also looks like the list's data-inset style is also not being applied: http://jsfiddle.net/6x9s9ys4/

Comment: Sorry, here you go, you can see the intended result by copy/pasting the template's html into the <ul>: http://jsfiddle.net/6x9s9ys4/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6x9s9ys4/7/ `.listview("refresh")`.

Comment: That change didn't solve it, also noticed that the icons are stacked in the JSFiddle instead of being inline (but they do display now!)

Comment: use _controlgroup_ for buttons http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8gkm1f8L/

Comment: controlgroup is not necessary, the solution is the call to .enhanceWithin() like you did in the latest fiddle. Thanks :) Please post this as an answer so I can credit you.